# RecyclerView with a SearchView error refiltering

Tags: android, filter, android-recyclerview

The input filter work fine but after erase some word then unable to show item in list. Re-filter is not working. I can't find a solution,

This is my Adapter class.

```
public class DealerListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DealerListAdapter.ViewHolderDealerList> {
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    public Context mcontext;
    private ArrayList<SuggestGetSet> dealerArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    Typeface type;
    private static String selectedRepId, selectedDealerId, selectedDealerName;

    public DealerListAdapter(Context context) {

        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        type = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "helvr.ttf");
    }

    public static String getDealerName() {
        return selectedDealerName;
    }

    public static String getDealerID() {
        return selectedDealerId;
    }

    public static String getRepID() {
        return selectedRepId;
    }

    public DealerListAdapter(ArrayList<SuggestGetSet> list, Context context) {
        this.mcontext = context;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.dealerArrayList = list;
        type = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "helvr.ttf");
    }

    public void setDealertList(ArrayList<SuggestGetSet> dealerAList) {
        this.dealerArrayList = dealerAList;
        notifyItemRangeChanged(0, dealerArrayList.size());
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolderDealerList onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dealer_list_layout, parent, false);
        ViewHolderDealerList viewHolderDealerList = new ViewHolderDealerList(view);
        return viewHolderDealerList;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderDealerList holder, int position) {
        final SuggestGetSet model = dealerArrayList.get(position);
        holder.bind(model);
        //SuggestGetSet currentDealer = dealerArrayList.get(position);
        //holder.dealerName.setText(currentDealer.getName());
        //holder.dealerName.setTypeface(type);
        final int pos = position;

        holder.dealerName.setText(dealerArrayList.get(position).getName());
        holder.dealerName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                selectedDealerId = dealerArrayList.get(pos).getDealerId();
                selectedRepId = dealerArrayList.get(pos).getId();
                selectedDealerName = dealerArrayList.get(pos).getName();

                Toast.makeText(layoutInflater.getContext(), dealerArrayList.get(pos).getName() + " / " + dealerArrayList.get(pos).getDealerId() + " / " + dealerArrayList.get(pos).getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dealerArrayList.size();
    }

    public void setModels(ArrayList<SuggestGetSet> models) {
        dealerArrayList = new ArrayList<>(models);
    }

    static class ViewHolderDealerList extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView dealerName, dealerId;

        public ViewHolderDealerList(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            dealerName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.yourDelaerName);
            dealerId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDelaerCollection);
        }

        public void bind(SuggestGetSet model) {
            dealerName.setText(model.getName());
        }

    }

    //search animations
    public SuggestGetSet removeItem(int position) {
        final SuggestGetSet model = dealerArrayList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        return model;
    }

    public void addItem(int position, SuggestGetSet model) {
        dealerArrayList.add(position, model);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    public void moveItem(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        final SuggestGetSet model = dealerArrayList.remove(fromPosition);
        dealerArrayList.add(toPosition, model);
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    }

    public void animateTo(ArrayList<SuggestGetSet> models) {
        applyAndAnimateRemovals(models);
        applyAndAnimateAdditions(models);
        applyAndAnimateMovedItems(models);
    }

    private void applyAndAnimateMovedItems(ArrayList<SuggestGetSet> models) {
        for (int toPosition = dealerArrayList.size() - 1; toPosition >= 0; toPosition--) {
            final SuggestGetSet model = dealerArrayList.get(toPosition);
            final int fromPosition = models.indexOf(model);
            if (fromPosition >= 0 && fromPosition != toPosition) {
                moveItem(fromPosition, toPosition);
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void applyAndAnimateAdditions(ArrayList<SuggestGetSet> models) {
        for (int i = 0, count = dealerArrayList.size(); i < count; i++) {
            final SuggestGetSet model = dealerArrayList.get(i);
            if (!models.contains(model)) {
                addItem(i, model);
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void applyAndAnimateRemovals(ArrayList<SuggestGetSet> models) {
        for (int i = dealerArrayList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            final SuggestGetSet model = dealerArrayList.get(i);
            if (!models.contains(model)) {
                removeItem(i);
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

This is my Fragment class.

```
public class YourDealerListFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private VollySingleton vollySingleton;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DealerListAdapter dlAdapter;
    private HashMap<String, String> hashMap;
    private ArrayList<SuggestGetSet> dealerList = new ArrayList<>();
    private String repNo;
    private StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager;
    private GridMenuFragment mGridMenuFragment;
    private Toolbar toolbar;


    public YourDealerListFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment YourDealerListFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static YourDealerListFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        YourDealerListFragment fragment = new YourDealerListFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
        vollySingleton = VollySingleton.getsInstance();
        requestQueue = vollySingleton.getmRequestQueue();


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_your_dealer_list, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.dealerListRecyclerView);

        getJsonRequest();

        //get data from sqlite
        final SQLiteHandler sqLiteHandler = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        Cursor cr = sqLiteHandler.getData(sqLiteHandler);
        cr.moveToFirst();

        do {
            repNo = cr.getString(0);
        } while (cr.moveToNext());

        cr.close();


        //listview
        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewChoose);


        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) view.findViewById(R.id.dealerNameSearchView);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(listener);

        //custom context menu
        mGridMenuFragment = GridMenuFragment.newInstance(R.drawable.background);
        setupGridMenu();


        mGridMenuFragment.setOnClickMenuListener(new GridMenuFragment.OnClickMenuListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClickMenu(GridMenu gridMenu, int position) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SelectItem.class);

                        startActivity(intent);
                        getActivity();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        //dealers' recycler view item click
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new NavigationDrawerFragment.RecycleTouchListner(getActivity(), recyclerView, new NavigationDrawerFragment.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {

                FragmentTransaction tx = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                tx.replace(R.id.main_frame, mGridMenuFragment);
                tx.addToBackStack(null);
                tx.commit();

            }
        }));


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        dealerList = new ArrayList<>();

        staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
        dlAdapter = new DealerListAdapter(dealerList,getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(dlAdapter);
    }

    //search dealer from search view
    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener listener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {

            return false;

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            final ArrayList<SuggestGetSet> filteredModelList = filter(dealerList, s);
            dlAdapter.animateTo(filteredModelList);
            recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
            dlAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;

        }
    };

    private ArrayList<SuggestGetSet> filter(ArrayList<SuggestGetSet> models, String query) {

        query = query.toLowerCase();
        if (query.equals("")) {
            dlAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return dealerList;

        }

        final ArrayList<SuggestGetSet> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (SuggestGetSet model : models) {
            final String text = model.getName().toLowerCase();
            if (text.contains(query)) {
                filteredModelList.add(model);
            }
        }
        return filteredModelList;
    }

    //custom context menu data
    private void setupGridMenu() {
        List<GridMenu> menus = new ArrayList<>();
        menus.add(new GridMenu("Order", R.drawable.nnn));
        menus.add(new GridMenu("Banking", R.drawable.n));
        menus.add(new GridMenu("Credit Note", R.drawable.nn));
        menus.add(new GridMenu("Cheques", R.drawable.nnnn));
        menus.add(new GridMenu("Invoice Dispatch", R.drawable.nnnnn));
        menus.add(new GridMenu("Goods Return", R.drawable.nnnnnn));

        mGridMenuFragment.setupMenu(menus);
    }


    private void getJsonRequest() {

        CustomJsonObjectRequest request = new CustomJsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.URL_JSON_DEALER_LIST, hashMap, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
                    if (jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("feed")) {
                        dealerList = parseJsonResponse(response);
                        dlAdapter.setDealertList(dealerList);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Dealers Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                /*dealerList = parseJsonResponse(response);
                dlAdapter.setDealertList(dealerList);*/
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }) {
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hashMap.put("repNo", repNo);
                return hashMap;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

    private ArrayList<SuggestGetSet> parseJsonResponse(JSONObject response) {
        ArrayList<SuggestGetSet> groupList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (response != null || response.length() > 0) {

            try {

                JSONArray arrayDelaers = response.getJSONArray(KEY_FEED_NAME);

                for (int i = 0; i < arrayDelaers.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject currentObject = arrayDelaers.getJSONObject(i);
                    String rep = currentObject.getString(KEY_REP_ID);
                    String name = currentObject.getString(KEY_REP_NAME);
                    String dealerId = currentObject.getString(KEY_DEALER_ID);

                    SuggestGetSet delaers = new SuggestGetSet();
                    delaers.setId(rep);
                    delaers.setName(name);
                    delaers.setDealerId(dealerId);

                    groupList.add(delaers);

                }
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), productList.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return groupList;
    }

    public static interface ClickListener {
        public void onClick(View view, int position);

        //public void onLongClick(View view, int position);

    }
}
```

This is my SuggestGetSet class.

```
public class SuggestGetSet {

    String dealer_id, rep_id, dealer_name;

    public SuggestGetSet() {

    }

    public SuggestGetSet(String dealer_id, String id, String name) {
        this.dealer_id=dealer_id;
        this.rep_id=id;
        this.dealer_name=name;
        /*this.setDealerId(dealer_id);
        this.setName(name);*/
    }

    public String getId() {
        return rep_id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.rep_id = id;
    }

    public String getDealerId() {
        return dealer_id;
    }

    public void setDealerId(String dealer_id) {
        this.dealer_id = dealer_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return dealer_name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.dealer_name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is you are using only one list in your adapter so once it data is removed it is never shown again.

I would suggest having two lists. One as complete list and another is the list you show. So when you search you can search the complete list and add relevant items to the list that you show.

Also this is not an optimal way to do the search as search is done in the main thread.

Try using Filterable. An example is as follows.

public class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter implements Filterable {

```
private ArrayList<YourModel> mCompleteList, mFilteredList;
private Context context;

public RecyclerLiquorAdapter(Context context ArrayList<LiquorItem> mCompleteList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mCompleteList = mCompleteList;
    mFilteredList = new ArrayList<>(mCompleteList);

}

@Override
public RecyclerLiquorAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
  //Your createViewHolder implementation


}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerLiquorAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {   
 //Your bindview holder implementation
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mFilteredList.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
   //Your view holder implementation
}



@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new MyFilter(this, mCompleteList);
}

public static class MyFilter extends Filter {

    private final MyAdapter adapter;

    private final List<Model> originalList;

    private final List<Model> filteredList;

    public LiquorFilter(RecyclerLiquorAdapter adapter, List<LiquorItem> originalList) {
        this.adapter = adapter;
        this.originalList = originalList;
        this.filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        filteredList.clear();
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        // We implement here the filter logic
        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
            // No filter implemented we return all the list
            filteredList.addAll(originalList);
        } else {
          //Implement your filter logic here

                }
            }
        }
        results.values = filteredList;
        results.count = filteredList.size();
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        // Now we have to inform the adapter about the new list filtered
        adapter.mFilteredList.clear();
        adapter.mFilteredList.addAll((ArrayList<LiquorItem>) results.values);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

By using this you can be sure that all your list manipulations are done in a background thread and your UI is not affected.

Comment: how to use two list and where should i put that original list for re-filtering in my code? can you give me suggestion for my code. i tried yours but with my implementation i have no idea how to use it. thank you

Comment: Just do this and try :  do not initialise dealerArrayList outside the constructor.  And then in your constructor instead of this.dealerArrayList = list; put in this.dealerArrayList = new ArrayList(list);  and try. It should work.

Comment: ok, how to access to filter method from my fragment ???how do I call to the adapter??

Comment: The previous comment was for your implementation.

Comment: If you want to access filter method you can just use. yourAdapter.getFilter().filter(<your query text>);